# Ideas for code refactoring typescript switch statement

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have the following Interfaces:

```
export  interface IListItem {
    [key: string]: any;
    id: string;
    title: string;
    modified: Date;
    created: Date;
    modifiedby: string;
    createdby: string;
}

import {IListItem} from "./IListItem";

export interface  IAnnouncementListItem extends IListItem {
    announcementBody: string;
    expiryDate: Date;
}


import {IListItem} from "./IListItem";

export interface IDirectoryListItem extends IListItem {
        firstName: string;
        lastName: string;
        mobileNumber: string;
        internalNumber: string;
}


import {IListItem} from "./IListItem";

export interface  INewsListItem extends IListItem {
    newsheader: string;
    newsbody: string;
    expiryDate: Date;
}
```

And I have the following Factory interface:

```
import { IListItem } from "./models/IListItem";
import { SPHttpClient, SPHttpClientResponse } from "@microsoft/sp-http";
export  interface IFactory {
    getItems(requester: SPHttpClient, siteUrl: string, listName: string): IListItem[];
}
```

And then I have the following class that implements this interface

```
import { SPHttpClient, SPHttpClientResponse } from "@microsoft/sp-http";
import { IWebPartContext } from "@microsoft/sp-webpart-base";
import { IListItem} from "./models/IListItem";
import { IFactory } from "./IFactory";
import { INewsListItem } from "./models/INewsListItem";
import { IDirectoryListItem } from "./models/IDirectoryListItem";
import { IAnnouncementListItem } from "./models/IAnnouncementListItem";

export class ListItemFactory implements IFactory {
    public getItems(requester: SPHttpClient, siteUrl: string, listName: string): IListItem[] {
        switch(listName) {
            case "List":
                let items: IListItem[];
                requester.get(`${siteUrl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('${listName}')/items?$select=Title,Id`,
                SPHttpClient.configurations.v1,
                {
                    headers: {
                        "Accept": "application/json;odata=nometadata",
                        "odata-version": ""
                    }
                })
                .then((response: SPHttpClientResponse): Promise<{ value: IListItem[] }> => {
                    return response.json();
                })
                .then((response: { value: IListItem[] }): void => {
                    items= response.value;
                });
                return items;
            case "News":
                let newsitems: INewsListItem[];
                requester.get(`${siteUrl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('${listName}')/items?$select=Title,Id`,
                SPHttpClient.configurations.v1,
                {
                    headers: {
                        "Accept": "application/json;odata=nometadata",
                        "odata-version": ""
                    }
                })
                .then((response: SPHttpClientResponse): Promise<{ value: INewsListItem[] }> => {
                    return response.json();
                })
                .then((response: { value: INewsListItem[] }): void => {
                    newsitems= response.value;
                });
                return newsitems;
            case "Announcements":
                let announcementitems: IAnnouncementListItem[];
                requester.get(`${siteUrl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('${listName}')/items?$select=Title,Id`,
                SPHttpClient.configurations.v1,
                {
                    headers: {
                        "Accept": "application/json;odata=nometadata",
                        "odata-version": ""
                    }
                })
                .then((response: SPHttpClientResponse): Promise<{ value: IAnnouncementListItem[] }> => {
                    return response.json();
                })
                .then((response: { value: IAnnouncementListItem[] }): void => {
                    announcementitems= response.value;
                });
                return announcementitems;
            case "Directory":
                let directoryitems: IDirectoryListItem[];
                requester.get(`${siteUrl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('${listName}')/items?$select=Title,Id`,
                SPHttpClient.configurations.v1,
                {
                    headers: {
                        "Accept": "application/json;odata=nometadata",
                        "odata-version": ""
                    }
                })
                .then((response: SPHttpClientResponse): Promise<{ value: IDirectoryListItem[] }> => {
                    return response.json();
                })
                .then((response: { value: IDirectoryListItem[] }): void => {
                    items= response.value;
                });
                return directoryitems;
            default:
                return null;
        }
      }
}
```

This last part is the one I dont like, I created a switch statement because depending on the list selected the return array will be of a different type, IListItem, IAnnouncementListItem, IDirectoryListItem or INewsListItem.

Any suggestion to make this method shorter>?

2nd. I call this from my react component like this:

```
 // read items using factory method pattern and sets state accordingly
  private readItemsAndSetStatus(): void {
    this.setState({
      status: "Loading all items..."
    });

    const factory: ListItemFactory = new ListItemFactory();
    const items: IListItem[] = factory.getItems(this.props.spHttpClient, this.props.siteUrl, this.props.listName);
    const keyPart: string = this.props.listName === "Items" ? "" : this.props.listName;

    // the explicit specification of the type argument `keyof {}` is bad and
    // it should not be required.
    this.setState<keyof {}>({
        status: `Successfully loaded ${items.length} items`,
        ["Details" + keyPart + "ListItemState"] : {
          items,
          columns: [
          ]
        }
      });
  }
```

But as you can see the getitems returns an array of ListItems, can this be improved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use this analog example to demonstrate a few techniques...

```
class Example {
    public getItems(requester: SPHttpClient, siteUrl: string, listName: string): IListItem[] {
        return [];
    }
}

const example = new Example();

// IListItem[]
const news = example.getItems(null, '', 'News');

// IListItem[]
const announcements = example.getItems(null, '', 'Announcements');
```

## Overloads

You could get back more specific types using method overloads with specialized signatures:

```
class Example {
    public getItems(requester: SPHttpClient, siteUrl: string, listName: 'News'): INewsListItem[];
    public getItems(requester: SPHttpClient, siteUrl: string, listName: 'Announcements'): IAnnouncementListItem[];
    public getItems(requester: SPHttpClient, siteUrl: string, listName: string): IListItem[];
    public getItems(requester: SPHttpClient, siteUrl: string, listName: string): IListItem[] {
        return [];
    }
}

const example = new Example();

// INewsListItem[]
const news = example.getItems(null, '', 'News');

// IAnnouncementListItem[]
const announcements = example.getItems(null, '', 'Announcements');
```

## Strategy Pattern

Instead of having the code for the lists within your big switch statement, you could break out classes and select the appropriate one...

```
class ListItemProvider {
    public getItems(requester: SPHttpClient, siteUrl: string): IListItem[] {
        // Just the code for list items
        return [];
    }
}

class NewsItemProvider {
    public getItems(requester: SPHttpClient, siteUrl: string): INewsListItem[] {
        // Just the code for news items
        return [];
    }
}

class AnnouncementItemProvider {
    public getItems(requester: SPHttpClient, siteUrl: string): IAnnouncementListItem[] {
        // Just the code for announcment items
        return [];
    }
}


class Example {
    public getItemProvider(listName: 'News'): NewsItemProvider;
    public getItemProvider(listName: 'Announcments'): AnnouncementItemProvider;
    public getItemProvider(listName: 'List' | 'News' | 'Announcments'): ListItemProvider;
    public getItemProvider(listName: 'List' | 'News' | 'Announcments') : ListItemProvider {
        switch (listName) {
            case 'List':
                return new ListItemProvider();
            case 'News':
                return new NewsItemProvider();
            case 'Announcments':
                return new AnnouncementItemProvider();
            default:
                throw new Error('No provider for ' + listName);
        }
    }
}

const example = new Example();

// INewsListItem[]
const news = example.getItemProvider('News').getItems(null, '');

// IAnnouncementListItem[]
const announcements = example.getItemProvider('Announcments').getItems(null, '');
```

You could then extract common code into a base class. Each part of the code is smaller, and easier to read. There are a few more parts, but they logically separate things.

There are some other ways to achieve what you are after, but these will point you in the right direction.